# specified list comprehensions

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Let say I've got two 1D list

```
firstList = [ "sample01", None, "sample02", "sample03", None ]
secondList = [ "sample01", "sample02", "sample03", None, None, None, "sample04"]
```

Now I'm looking for recipe for listComprehension that will return `firstList`,`secondList` but without None objects.

So it should look like this

```
listComprehension_List = [  [ "sample01","sample02","sample03" ] ,  [ "sample01","sample02","sample03", "sample04"  ]     ]
listComprehension_List = [[firstList without NONE objects],[secondList without NONE objects]]
```

I'm looking forward for any input ... now I will continue to try!

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> firstList = [ "sample01", None, "sample02", "sample03", None ]
>>> secondList = [ "sample01", "sample02", "sample03", None, None, None, "sample04"]
```

With a list comp

```
>>> [x for x in firstList if x is not None]
['sample01', 'sample02', 'sample03']
```

or you can just use `filter`

```
>>> filter(None, secondList)
['sample01', 'sample02', 'sample03', 'sample04']
```

For both:

```
>>> [[y for y in x if y is not None] for x in (firstList, secondList)]
[['sample01', 'sample02', 'sample03'], ['sample01', 'sample02', 'sample03', 'sample04']]
```

Comment: Hi jamylak . Oh that's fast :) . But I need kind of list of lists listComprehension_List = [[firstList without NONE objects],[secondList without NONE objects]]

Comment: That's great!!!!  I would spent another few hours without it Thanks!!. So it need to be NESTED ? Just curiousity

Comment: @bolek It's much better nested than writing it twice, you could easily copy paste the first solution in my code if you wanted to do that of course

Comment: Sure ... You're right... It was just curiosity . I'm writting simple "learning" code so I don't want to miss any interesting solutions. Thanks Again!!